# How can GPIO output states survive process exit?

Tags: c, embedded-linux

From formerly known sysfs interface anyone could set an output of a reasonable configured GPIO line and this output will keep the value until the SoC is reset or someone changes the line value.
With GPIOlib, the value is reset to the initial value when the consumer closes the handle to the gpiochip.
Assumed, the GPIO line controls a hydraulic system which opens or closes a door - when the application (consumer) is killed for whatever reason, the door opens or closes (likely closes) - whatever the default line setting was.

I did some web-search and read the docs (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/index.html), played around with the examples delivered by https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/.

Finally - the result is always the same: when the process exits, the line is reset.
Is there any chance to persist a particular line value?

Comment: Not really - it belongs to the GPIOlib API and how to use it. Posting the examples wouldn't improve the question.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correclly - if app is killed then gpio is not reset and if app exists gracefully it is reset?

Comment: Can you create a small program to test it? It would be something like `gpiod_line_request_output` followed by `raise(SIGKILL)`, right?

Comment: @ryyker this questions is very specifically about the behavior of the linux kernel gpio driver (and the gpiolib library that is used to interact with it in C). Seems better here than there.

Comment: @Zaffy: Mope, the line is reset anytime the process exits - regardless the reason.

Comment: @ryyker: It has nothing to do with electrical engineering - it's specifically regarding the new GPIO API of the linux kernel (compared to the legacy, deprecated one).

Comment: @KamilCuk: see https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/tools/gpioset.c or https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/bindings/cxx/examples/gpiosetcxx.cpp

Comment: Brrr, this is too likely to kill door consumers.  The odds that you can get this deployed and meet local regulations ought to be quite slim.

Comment: The  first example you linked uses `gpiod_ctxless_set_value_multiple`, the second one closes gpiod in c++ destructor. If someone wanted to test your assumption, it would be really helpful if you would create an example for them to easy compile, run and test, or maybe you have written such a program and tested it yourself, that's why I asked.

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes. That's why I named both. When a process is killed, the gpio-handle is always closed by the kernel. And then the line is reset. It doesn't matter whether the process is terminated in a regular way (by exiting or returning from main) or killing it using a signal.

Comment: `And then the line is reset.` - why? I guess this depends on what gpio driver does on it's release. I don't think anything should happen on close, but maybe something happens. There is nothing really in [release](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L432). `Since it's a regression` - did you test it? If yes, how?

Comment: @KamilCuk: I guess similar - but I want to know. And I want to know if it's possible (and if yes, how) to modify this behavior. Since it's a regression compared to former API.

Comment: @KamilCuk: How much do you know about Linux GPIO API that you ask whether writing into sysfs exports of gpio compared to reset values after closing a gpiochip fd isn't a regression.
There can't be a reset in sysfs API - otherwise you would have to keep any file handle open until system reboot. Yes, it's common sense that the line keeps the value after writing into a SYSFS_ENTRY.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I have tested it using the `gpiod` user apps.  This char dev API was DoA.

Answer (score 2):

From the source of gpioset.c (https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/blob/master/tools/gpioset.c):

```
printf("Note: the state of a GPIO line controlled over the character device reverts to default\n");
printf("when the last process referencing the file descriptor representing the device file exits.\n");
printf("This means that it's wrong to run gpioset, have it exit and expect the line to continue\n");
printf("being driven high or low. It may happen if given pin is floating but it must be interpreted\n");
printf("as undefined behavior.\n");
```

Works as designed...

For me, I miss a feature, where the line stays (is locked) in the state I have set.
It is definitely a regression compared to sysfs with its export mechanism.

Comment: `"I miss a feature, where the line stays in the state I have set."` I second that emotion.

Comment: I understand this answer as a confirmation of the regression. So there is at the moment in time no reasonable solution but an stateful service.